# How to open this conical tap trimming?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I need to fix the leaking tap but problem is I am not able to open this cover. I have tried dousing it in WD-40 but even that didn't work. I have tried strap wrench but it does not give much grip. It is screwed to the tap assembly.

[image]

Comment: I might look for a set screw securing it take the handle off to give more room to work may also help, last sometimes trying a slight tightening loosens things up sounds crazy but many times when I think I am about to break something I go the other direction and get a slight movement, more penetrating oil and unscrew if I get a little and it locks up back tight with more oil going back and forth works the oil into the threads and may help.

Comment: I'll give the tightening bit a try @EdBeal. I've removed handle. The cover is screwed on to the base of tap assembly (into which the spindle goes).

Comment: High-friction-rubber jar opening assist? Drill a hole and insert a nail or something like that as a pry handle? Try using a nail set at the edge to tap it around counterclockwise?  I think the simple answer is that no matter what you do it's going to be ugly.